# Error en array android studio JAVA

Tags: java, android

Obtengo este error ;

> attempt to get length of null array

En el siguiente codigo:

```
    try {


    path = rutas.obtener_ruta();
    carpeta = new File(path);
    listado = carpeta.list();
    imagenes= new ArrayList();


    for (int a=0;a<listado.length;a++)
    {
        if (   (obtener_extension(listado[a]).equalsIgnoreCase("jpg"))  || (obtener_extension(listado[a]).equalsIgnoreCase("JPG")) || (obtener_extension(listado[a]).equalsIgnoreCase("png")) || (obtener_extension(listado[a]).equalsIgnoreCase("PNG")) )
        {
            imagenes.add(path + listado[a]);
        }
    }




}
catch(Exception gfgf)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, gfgf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

He comprobado que la ruta que almacena "path" si existe, en *Android 9* funciona bien pero tengo un Android que dice tener *Android 10* y me da ese error.

Actualizacion:
He comprobado mediante codigo y las rutas si existen

```
public String obtener_ruta() {
    ruta1 = new File(ruta_interna);
    ruta2 = new File(ruta_externa);

    if (ruta1.isDirectory()) {
        return "storage/emulated/0/DCIM/";

    } else {
        return "storage/emulated/0/DCIM/";

    }

}
```

Comment: Saludos, mmm al parecer el error podria estar en la forma que listas los directorios en **rutas.obtener_ruta()** podrias también añadir este método en la decripción de tu problema para ver verificarlo

Comment: Ya actualice con el metodo rutas.obtener_ruta();

Comment: Cabe recalcar que en Android  8,9,6 si funciona bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno realice una verificación a tu código.

Primeramente recomendaria utilizar `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` en lugar de una ruta fija, ejemplo:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "DCIM";
File file = new File(path);
if (file.isDirectory())
    return path;
```

Ahora bien no olvides que deberás otorgar permisos para acceder a los directorios `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` o `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` según requieras, puedes encontrar información para los permisos en [este enlace](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419).

Lo probé en *Android 10*, espero te funcione. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por comentar aun asi tenia errores al querer acceder a imagenes en Android 10, en un foro encontré con que agregar un permiso en el AndroidManifest dentro del meta "application" y eso soluciono mi problema:

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Esto no tiene que ver con la respuesta que marcaste como solución :|